# GetSaveAsFilename() ALWAYS opens in My Documents

Tags: vba, save

I have a problem with getting GetSaveAsFileName() function to open Save dialogue box in a Network drive instead of always opening in my documents.
 Basically, I have implemented a workaround to change path to a network drive via:

Top of my working module:

```
 Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
 "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long

 Sub ChDirNet(szPath As String)
 Dim lReturn As Long
 lReturn = SetCurrentDirectoryA(szPath)
 If lReturn = 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "Error setting path."
 End Sub
```

In my SaveAs() module the following code:

```
 ChDirNet "\\test\input"
 xFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("\\test\input\filename.xls")
```

However, I STILL can not get the save as dialogue box to open in the \test\input network path.

Can someone please advice?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with *networking* or *directory*. It has to do with using `GetSaveAsFilename`. Please [edit] to remove the non-applicable tags and add one for the language you're using (VBA?); it will vastly improve your chances of getting help if you tag it properly. Read the descriptions of tags before just randomly adding those that sound familiar - tags have specific meanings here.

Comment: You could try mapping the path to a drive letter.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to avoid mapping to a drive and using ChDr function so this is not a solution... I am trying to figure out why my network path isn't parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- There is no need to do a Change Dir before calling
- I just did some
  tests and `GetSaveAsFilename` works perfectly when you pass a valid
  folder or file in UNC notation.
- I have the suspicion that your
  network path is invalid. Are you sure that the network path is
  correct (can you open the explorer with this path) ?

Comment: The funny thing is, GetSaveAsFilename opens the right network path on my PC but goes to My Documents on my users' PC. But they can open/access the path manually in Windows Explorer...